# Is it safe to use "throw" without releasing Mutex in win32?

Tags: winapi, mutex, throw

First of all, I tested it and it worked well.
I want to know whether it is correct or not.

```
funcA() {  
    DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
    if (aaa != bbb) throw "aaa";

    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
}
```

WaitForSingleObject always returns "0", not "WAIT_ABANDONED" or any other error codes.
I just can't find any documentation that describes Mutex would be released on "throw".

Thank you

Comment: If you coninually call funcA() from the same thread then that is the expected behaviour - WAIT_OBJECT_0 is returned because Windows mutexes are recursive.  If you call funcA() from a different thread the second time, I would expect the call to block until the first thread releases the mutex.

Comment: You are right. I'm using xmlrpc library and I thought there is multiple threads for handling request but there is only one thread. So, it was expected behavior and my Mutex is unnecessary! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the mutex won't be release on throw.

You can, however, build your own `Lock` class that locks the mutex on the constructor, and releases it on it's destructor. Then, if you use a `Lock` object in your function (using the memory stack, not the heap), you can ensure that the destructor for that object will be called and the mutex released.

This is exactly what the [CSingleLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwk62eb7.aspx) class does in MFC.

Comment: Also CComAutoCriticalSection and CComCriticalSectionLock in ATL.

Answer (score 1):

It won't unless releasing is called implicitly in destructor or catch block. Do you show the whole code needed to describe it?